# Tkinter Dynamic Widget editing

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
class render_window:
    def __init__(self, height, width, window_title):
        self.root_window = Tk()
        w = width
        h = height
        ws = self.root_window.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
        hs = self.root_window.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
        x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
        y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
        self.root_window.title(window_title)
        self.root_window.minsize(width, height)
        self.root_window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

    def new_button(self, button_text, button_command="", grid_row=0, grid_column=0, grid_sticky="NESW", grid_columnspan=1, grid_rowspan=1):
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.root_window, text=button_text, command=button_command)
        self.button.grid(row=grid_row, column=grid_column, sticky=grid_sticky, columnspan=grid_columnspan, rowspan=grid_rowspan)
        self.responsive_grid(grid_row, grid_column)

    def new_label(self, label_text, text_alignment="center", grid_row=0, grid_column=0, grid_sticky="NESW", grid_columnspan=1, grid_rowspan=1):
        self.label = ttk.Label(self.root_window, text=label_text, anchor=text_alignment)
        self.label.grid(row=grid_row, column=grid_column, sticky=grid_sticky, columnspan=grid_columnspan, rowspan=grid_rowspan)
        self.responsive_grid(grid_row, grid_column)

    def new_progress_bar(self, pg_length=250, pg_mode="determinate", grid_row=0, grid_column=0, grid_sticky="NESW", grid_columnspan=1, grid_rowspan=1):
        self.progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self.root_window, length=pg_length, mode=pg_mode)
        self.progress_bar.grid(row=grid_row, column=grid_column, sticky=grid_sticky, columnspan=grid_columnspan, rowspan=grid_rowspan)
        self.responsive_grid(grid_row, grid_column)

    def responsive_grid(self, row_responsive=0, column_responsive=0, row_weight_num=1, column_weight_num=1):
        self.root_window.grid_columnconfigure(column_responsive, weight=column_weight_num)
        self.root_window.grid_rowconfigure(row_responsive, weight=row_weight_num)

options_window = render_window(200, 250, "Options Window")

options_window.new_progress_bar()
options_window.progress_bar.start()
options_window.new_progress_bar(grid_column=1)
options_window.progress_bar.start()
options_window.new_label("Options Window\And other buttons...", grid_row=1, grid_columnspan=2)

options_window.root_window.mainloop()
```

I have created a system that allows the creation of an interface relatively easily using tkinter. I am having an issue with the modifying of already existing elements, I cannot seem to modify them if I create multiple instances, I can only edit the last one created. when I say modify/edit, I am talking about .config().

So whenever I do:
options_window.progress_bar.config(args_here), it only does that for the last bar created. Is there a way to specify which bar I can execute the code on?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a list or dictionary  to keep a reference to each widget

Comment: @BryanOakley, How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly... could you not just asign each progressbar to a variable? Ie.

```
pb1 = options_window.progress_bar
pb1.start()
pb1.conig('etc, etc')
```

Sorry if i have misunderstood your problem!

PS - Cool idea!

Comment: I totally forgot about that. Let me get my code updated and tested. Thx for the quick reply!

Comment: Edit:
Just got it, will do more testing. A code error was present. I fixed it. You might want to drop "()" for the progress bar var. it ain't a function.

Comment: As soon as you update your answer I will mark it as such. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Elliot I have removed the brackets. Does this look ok now?

Comment: And as Brian says you can then append your variables to a list and iterate through them all at once or individually. IE [pb1, pb2]

Comment: Ahhh, makes sense. I understand now. Thanks!